# Help decrypting Encrypted Privated Keys (AES)

Tags: wallet, private-key

I am manually inputting my encrypted private keys and secret key (password) on https://www.browserling.com/tools/aes-decrypt

Is there a way I can input more than 1 encrypted private key at a time? I have hundreds of encrypted private keys I want to check for any btc balance.

Comment: Why do you trust this website with your money?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way I can input more than 1 encrypted private key at a time?

Write [a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155932/how-do-you-loop-through-each-line-in-a-text-file-using-a-windows-batch-file) using [OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056135/how-to-use-openssl-to-encrypt-decrypt-files)

> I have hundreds of encrypted private keys I want to check for any btc balance.

You should be prepared that they'll all have zero balance soon after typing them into public websites run by people you don't know anything about. Even if the proprietors are honest, you are also putting temptation in front of their new, temporary, weak-willed or disgruntled employees and their third-party support staff and malicious hackers.